# search for mounted hard drive by serial number

Tags: hard-drive, python

Is there a way to check if a hard drive exists using just it's serial number?

I'd like to use this in python

Comment: What do you mean with exists?

Comment: I executed the command `udisksctl dump` and saw Serial: numbers for my HD and DVD-RW drives, so the information is available.